# Whats more optimal 8 ViewControllers or 1 ViewController and Adjust buttons in ViewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

So I need 8 Scenes which are almost identical.

They are all subviews of a single superview.

The 1st scene has 33 buttons in a particular layout. 2nd scene has the same buttons (minus 3) in an adjusted layout. 3rd scene...minus 3 more buttons and more adjusted layout..etc

**which would make my app more optimal on memory/CPU?**

1. 8 `subviewcontrollers` with storyboarded layouts
2. 1 `subviewcontroller` that hides X number of buttons and adjusts the remaining buttons constraints accordingly in `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: Do the buttons do the same actions? Does your app support auto-layout?

Comment: You seem to be asking the wrong questions. Performance will be negligible, but code maintainability and extension surely will suffer in the latter case. Don't chase performance so preemptively, good design usually yields good performance and maintainability.

First analyze what the actual differences are between these screens to determine proper code reuse. If it is just button text, color, visibility, or some minor appearance then re-use your view controllers. If you need more advanced functionality, make another view controller for it.

I personally favor splitting things up, much cleaner.

Comment: @Erik_at_Digit **splitting this up**, you mean 8 subviewcontrollers? I know my performance questions might be preemptive but I am entirely new to computer science and self-teaching.

Comment: @TravisM. yes they will function the same. But their position on the screen will be different for each scene and some would need to be hidden.

Comment: @Dustin It is hard to say what you are trying to do without a representation of what you mean. Are you changing screens (`UIViewController`) or just showing a single one with a set of subviews?

Comment: i have main screen (superview), a segmentedControl 2-8 which will segue to one of the eight screens (subviews)...but it seems best to do one subview and hide buttons and adjust their position based on # chosen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is regarding the choice to make at the time of implementation. As far as optimal performance on Runtime Memory/CPU is to be considered, there is no better approach over other, assuming only one view controller is visible at a time.

1) The factors, you may want to consider before choosing your design are:
What percentage of functionality is common to these controllers?

2) Time it could save for you when fixing a defect in one of the common functionality (1 Subviewcontroller definitely is the definite choice here).

3) How comfortable are you in handling the complexity arisen due to common code being used in common controller class.

Comment: 1) very high % 2) 1 VC would be more time saving 3) Im not sure, do you mean just having multi `UIButton` named `X1` X2` etc

Comment: "there is no better approach over other", this was my question. I didn't want to do one and find out at the end that my app would run smoother had i done the other. Thus it seems 1 VC with adjustments would be best. ty